# Run time form size shrunk from designed size

Tags: winforms, size, resolution

Been working on a C# code with MySql backend. Recently, there is a need to change my work computer from my office computer to a remote virtual computer. The very first form I designed on the remote computer, the size got shrunk unwantedly at run time, while other forms that were designed on my desktop were of the same size from design time to run time.

I tried to change the form's AutoSizeMode and set the Minumum Size the same as the designed size, neither worked. I searched in this forum and found the remote computer display resolution was different from my desktop, then I changed the remote resolution to match my desktop's, still not working.

Can anybody give me some clues? Thanks a lot...

Here are the design view and run time view:

Design view

[image: 1]

Run time view

[image: 2]

Comment: Try to set `AutoScaleMode` to `Dpi`.

Comment: Thanks a million, Kyle. It works.